# MySQL full join query displaying records that do not fit criteria

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I am building a hotel reservation system in C#, as a portfolio project to show employers when I get out of college.

My main form has a Month Calendar object, that once a date is clicked, it will update a DataGridView with all the rooms; and if there is a reservation in that room for that date, it will be displayed.

In the MySQL database, the 2 tables I am using are 'Rooms' and 'Reservations'

I will include images with the sample data that also show the column headers.

Since I learned SQL using MSSQL, MySQL is causing me a bit of trouble.

For the main form to show the data properly, I need the query to return ALL rooms, and whether or not there is a reservation in that room for the specified date. Through some research, I found that a full join would be the correct join as it shows all fields from both tables. Since MySQL does not support full joins, I found a way to emulate it using

```
SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
LEFT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
UNION
SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
RIGHT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
WHERE
    rs.CheckInDate <= CURRENT_DATE
AND CAST((rs.CheckInDate + rs.NumberOfNights) AS DATE) > CURRENT_DATE
```

The Where clause basically says to only display reservations that have a check in date of before or on the date, and a checkout date of after the date. Basically showing a reservation that is active on that date.

However, the sample reservation is showing 100% of the time, even when it does not meet the criteria of the where clause. The join on key part of the query works well, as the reservation is displayed next to the correct room, but it looks like the where clause does not function as desired.

I am not sure how to proceed with this, so any help to get me on the right track would be appreciated.

Thanks

[Reservations Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQSwx.png)
[Rooms Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKYMA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a `FULL JOIN`; a `LEFT JOIN` from `ROOMS` will give you all rows in `ROOMS` regardless of whether there are any matching reservations. The key issue is to put any conditions on values from `RESERVATIONS` into the `ON` condition so that you don't convert the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-optimization.html)) which will then not give you any rooms which don't have reservations. Note you can also optimise your date comparison by using [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) and date arithmetic:

```
SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
LEFT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
  AND CURDATE() BETWEEN rs.CheckInDate AND rs.CheckInDate + INTERVAL rs.NumberOfNights - 1 DAY
```

Comment: That worked well.

It is also much more compact than what I had, and easier to understand when reading through the query.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `where` clause to the result of the `union` in a sub-select. An alternative would be to apply the where clause on the individual `select`.
So your query becomes-

```
SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
LEFT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
WHERE
rs.CheckInDate <= CURRENT_DATE
AND CAST((rs.CheckInDate + rs.NumberOfNights) AS DATE) > CURRENT_DATE

UNION

SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
RIGHT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
WHERE
rs.CheckInDate <= CURRENT_DATE
AND CAST((rs.CheckInDate + rs.NumberOfNights) AS DATE) > CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `union` for this. just use `or` operator on your date criteria

```
SELECT * FROM ROOMS r
LEFT JOIN RESERVATIONS rs ON r.RoomNumber = rs.RoomNumberReserved
WHERE 1=1 or 
    current_date() between rs.CheckInDate and cast((rs.CheckInDate + rs.NumberOfNights) AS date)
```